# Calibrate laptop display to simulate TN display problems

Tags: display

I am a web developer and I have had issues where designs have too little contrast, and customers complain, but it looks fine on my nice MBP display.  Most of the computers at Best Buy are sold with crappy panels, and I agree with the customer than on cheap displays, there is too little contrast.

Is there a way to simulate a typical Cheap TN panel in OSX?

Comment: Are you certain your own display is accurate in the first place? Nothing beats a hardware colorimeter, even a cheap one like the [ColorMunki Smile](http://www.xrite.com/custom_page.aspx?PageID=345)

Answer (score 1):

Since choosing the "right" color is a personal choice, I would recommend to use the ColorSync Utility located in your Utility folder.

Here you can set what profile to use or adjust the settings to your needs.

[image: profiles]

If you need to you can get ICC profile that suits your needs from [here](http://www.tftcentral.co.uk/articles/icc_profiles.htm#install).

Comment: This is where you would go to *apply* the profile, but making one in the first place is something else. It should be possible to make a profile with a response curve that simulates the blown out highlights/shadows and poor contrast of a TN panel but I have yet to discover a tool which can create the profile.